# Ubuntu 20.04 dvd player not mounting

Tags: mount, dvd

My desktop machine is running in dual boot with 16.04 and 20.04, with the Unity desktop in both versions. It has an internal DVD+R player. When a disk is inserted, the player spins but will not mount under 20.04, yet it mounts and is readable under 16.04.
The device is listed in Disks, but not in gparted.
Any useful advice will be appreciated.